# How to find client computer name in java script/jsp?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

My print application has to get the client name and then print the documents. How to find this in java script or jsp? I searched here. Some are discussing on PHP and so?
Something discussed about running secure applet to get the client computer name? If so please give me example to do that?
Thanks to all

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with Javascript. Try building a Java applet and:

```
java.net.InetAddress i = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost();
System.out.println(i.getHostName());
```

Answer (score 0):

For MSIE on windows you can use this:

```
<script type="text/jscript">
<!--
var net = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
alert(net.ComputerName);
//-->
</script>
```

...but: the page has to be "trusted"!(and of course jscript is not javascript)

Answer (score 0):

> How to find this in java script or jsp?

You cannot do this in a JSP, because the JSP executes on the server side.  (In theory a JSP could try to determine the client IP address from the request object via the `getRemoteAddr()` method, but this will fail if the user's browser accesses the server via a web proxy.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible using only JSP. I believe you'll need to execute some code on the client, and that code will probably need to be signed.You may be able to do it by included a signed applet that executes on the client PC and then sends the relevant information to your server. You might also be able to do it with JScript or VBScript.Here's the code to get windows username in javascript.

```
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         var WshNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
         alert (WshNetwork.UserName);
     </script>
```

This code snippet will work only in Internet Explorer because Internet Explorer deals with ActiveX Controls.