# how use java applet in asp.net without installing java runtime?

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, applet

i am new in java applet ...
where can i learn more about java applet (related to asp.net) and is it possible to use java applet in asp.net without installing java run time ?
mean is there a library for java on the net that we can refer it ?
(how ?)
for example how can i use below java applet codes without forcing my users to install some thing on their machines?
[How to find client computer name in java script/jsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964595/how-to-find-client-computer-name-in-java-script-jsp)

**mean Júlio Santos answer**

thanks in advance

Comment: This question seems vague and could use some context. It also seems like there are multiple questions being asked, but I'm not sure. It may be one, worded differently three different times...

Comment: +1 to offset the downvote.
English is obviously not this individual's first language; cut him some slack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you mentioned uses ActiveX (built into IE) and JScript (also built into IE). You do not need the Java Virtual Machine to be installed for that.

In general, running a Java Applet in ASP.NET does not make sense because Applets are client side (they run in the browser) while ASP.NET is (mainly) server side. You can use [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) to compile the Applet into something .NET understands but that basically gives you access to its public methods which may or may not help depending on your use case.

Here's how you can have IE auto install the JVM runtime: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaLP/javawebstart/AutoInstall.html

Comment: dear Jibaly -> my mean wat answer #2

Comment: not sure what answer #2 is, do u mean Julio's answer? You'd have to use a Java applet.

Comment: You can use that IE autoinstaller to install Java (added to answer).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Java without having the runtime installed.

The easiest way to do so, is to let the user navigate to java.com.

Comment: thanks for answer ! is n't there src attribute or something like that for applet or object elements like <script src="http://www.alfa.com/alibab.js"> element ? if not , after i installed java runtime , how can i use those java codes in the upper link ? (they look like server-side codes)

Comment: It must be installed by the user. Simply require your user to install Java in order to use this feature on your site. Most people already have it installed, anyway.